# Validating forms based on component input property

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 5 component with a reactive form and I want to validate one of the fields based on the value of a property passed in via @Input that may change.  I'm having no luck and it's causing errors as I try various solutions.  This is what I have so far (irrelevant code removed).

Thank you for any help, pointers to examples would be greatly appreciated.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-fief-budget',
  templateUrl: './fief-budget.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fief-budget.component.scss']
})
export class FiefBudgetComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('manor') manor: Manor;

....

  createForm() {
    this.budgetForm = this.fb.group({
      woodsWorked: [0, [Validators.required, Validators.min(0), this.validateMaxWoodacres]]
    });
  }

....

  validateMaxWoodacres(): ValidatorFn {
    return (c: FormControl) => {
      if (this.manor) {
        return c.value > this.manor.woodlandAcres ? { 'validateMaxWoodacres': {valid: false} } : null;
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Read this: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators

Comment: Thanks.  I have and this isn't helpful.  I can create a separate function and pass in manor, but this only passes in a copy as far as I can tell and doesn't update validation if the property I'm validating against on manor changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the replies.  I did figure this out and wanted to post here for anyone else seeking a solution.  The Input setters/getter method had problems in that it would fire before the form was defined and it didn't update as I would expect.  The suggestion of (re)setting validators though got me on the right road so thank you.

Ultimately where this seemed to actually work for me was to us the DoCheck lifecycle hook to reset the validators and also, I had to call update value and validity as well.  So I set the validators on the form initially and reset them here within the component class, no custom validation needed since max is updated to the current value of manor.woodlandAcres.

```
  ngDoCheck() {
    this.budgetForm.controls['woodsWorked'].setValidators([
      Validators.required,
      Validators.min(0),
      Validators.max(this.manor.woodlandAcres)]);
    this.budgetForm.controls['woodsWorked'].updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying wont't work, you will need to update your validator on input change:

```
private _manor: Manor;

@Input('manor')
set manor(manor: Manor) {
  this._manor = manor;
  // you can either update the form validators or just the validator of a single control
  this.bugetForm.setValidators(...)
}

get manor(): Manor {
  return this._manor;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  None of these are working.  the update doesn't work when the object being passed is updated.  I'll try to figure out an async validator perhaps?  Not sure still but I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

when we're using a function to make a validator, we need call to the function -to put the ()-

```
 this.budgetForm = this.fb.group({
      woodsWorked: [0, [Validators.required, Validators.min(0),
                        this.validateMaxWoodacres()]] //<--see the "parenthesis
    });
```

Be Carefully, if you expect change the value of "manor" after create the form, you must check again the form to validate again. That's you must make some like

```
  _manor:any;
  @Input('manor') 
  set manor(value){ //If a change of manor happens
    this._manor=value;
    if (this.budgetForm)  //if this.budgetForm
          this.budgetForm.get('woodsWorked').updateValueAndValidity(); //validate the control again
  }
  get manor() {
    return this._manor;
  }
```

NOTE: If we write without parenthesis

```
this.budgetForm = this.fb.group({
      woodsWorked: [0, [this.validateMaxWoodacres]] //without parenthesis
    });
```

Our function must be simply

```
validateMaxWoodacres(c: FormControl) {
    //but, we can NOT use "this" here
    return null;
}
```